# SQL 2008, how does it link Full Text Catalog to a filegroup

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, filegroups

While creating Full Text Catalog, if "on filegroup" is specified - it creates the catalog on this file, but on MSDN I read "On Filegroup" clause has no affect?

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate of [How to set full text catalog location SQL 2008/2011](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/how-to-set-full-text-catalog-location-sql-2008-2011).

Comment: Can you please provide the MSDN link where it says that.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm aware on how to set the location. As we are moving to 2008, I was advised to use 'filegroup' clause while creating full text catalog but MSDN states that this cluase has no effect in 2008. The confusion has been sorted out - In 2008, 'filegroup' clause should be used while creating the Full Text Index, where as in 2005 does not have this on Full Text Index command. @Stan the DBA - here is the link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189520(v=SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2005 and prior, you could specify the filegroup for full text.

In SQL Server 2008 and newer, full text is completely different, and the ON FILEGROUP stuff doesn't matter.  However, Microsoft doesn't just rip out syntax - they deprecate it, and a few versions later, it'll disappear.  (Backup log with truncate_only is a good example of this.)  This gives you time to clean up your scripts before the syntax disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in SQL Server 2008, full text catalogs are now virtual and filegroups are associated with the full text index instead of the catalog:

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189520.aspx):

> Beginning with SQL Server 2008, a full-text catalog is a virtual
>   object and does not belong to any filegroup. A full-text catalog is a
>   logical concept that refers to a group of full-text indexes.

The ON FILEGROUP clause still exists (for backwards compatibility with existing scripts), but has no effect.

However, the filegroup option is now available for the full-text index itself.  Therefore, instead of creating multiple catalogs--one for each file group--you can create one catalog and specify the filegroup for each full text index.

Basically, they have moved the filegroup mapping from the Catalog level to the Index level to allow for fewer catalogs and finer control.